# Stuck on passing data to a "favorite" list, need tips

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, ejs

I was given a coding exercise today by a company I am interviewing for. It's just a simple weather app that pulls data from openweathermap api. I've coded all the back end logic (which is what the test is for) using express, node, and ejs. However, the company wanted me to use a pre-made Bootstrap template for the index.html (or index.ejs in my case). The layout is simple. What I'm stuck on is that there is a button to add cities to a favorite list. And then there is a list that displays the favorites.

I need help implementing the functionality for this button. I'm sure this seems like a really noob question but I am just completely stuck on this part.

So here is the list that I need to populate dynamically when a user clicks on the Add to favorites button:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Miami Beach Florida
button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="display: inline; float: right;">X</button></a> 
 
<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Austin Texas
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="display: inline; float: right;">X</button></a>

<a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Williamsburg Virginia
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="display: inline; float: right;">X</button></a>

</ul>
```

Here is the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add To Favorites!</button>
```

Back end code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const request = require('request');

const api_key = 'a8b497ec94fc3d6f1a14044d575f5bca';

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    city: null,
    description: null,
    humidity: null,
    temp: null,
    wind: null,
    precipitation: null
  })
})

app.post('/', async function (req, res) {
    const zipcode = req.body.zipcode;
    const url_api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zipcode}&appid=${api_key}`
    console.log(req.body.zipcode);

    try {
       await fetch(url_api).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data.message === "city not found") {
                res.render('index', {
                    city: data.message,
                    description: null,
                    humidity: null,
                    temp: null,
                    wind: null,
                    precipitation: null
                })
            } else {
                const city = data.name;
                const description = data.weather[0].description;
                const wind = data.wind.speed;
                const temp = data.main.temp;
                const humidity = data.main.humidity;
                const precipitation = data.rain;

                res.render('index', {
                    city, description, wind, temp, humidity, precipitation
                });
            }
        });

    } catch(err) {
        res.render('index', {
            city: 'There was an error',
            description: null,
            humidity: null,
            temp: null,
            wind: null,
            precipitation: null,
        })
    }
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: post your code what have you tried then it will be easy to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just posted some of the html

Comment: why there are `three buttons` with the `city's name`? Because cities need to be pulled from the `APIs` and after clicking on the Favourites button it will show in the list right?

Comment: Those buttons are supposed to be "remove" buttons. The city names are just place holders. When the page is first loaded I need it to just be empty. And then when I search a city, I can add it to favorites and then have it show in the list.

Comment: can you show me your `back-end` code also?

Comment: posted it in an edit